# How to use ROWNUM with nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, rownum

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT PART_NO, SRC_PART_NO, CTNM_ENG, DESCRIPTION, USER_ID, REG_DT, CHG_DT, FLAG,       
(select count(*) from ( SELECT PART_NO, SRC_PART_NO, CTNM_ENG, DESCRIPTION, USER_ID, REG_DT, CHG_DT, FLAG
FROM GM_PART_LIST
WHERE PART_NO LIKE  '%' || '%' AND SRC_PART_NO LIKE  '%' || '%' AND CTNM_ENG LIKE  'BOLT'|| '%'
AND 1 = 1) ) as total_count -- Nested subquery that return total count of record set. plug in same where conditions.
FROM GM_PART_LIST
WHERE PART_NO LIKE  '%' || '%' AND SRC_PART_NO LIKE  '%' || '%' AND CTNM_ENG LIKE  'BOLT'|| '%'
AND 1 = 1
ORDER BY PART_NO ASC))
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 2 AND 202;
```

How is it that with the above query if I search between 1 and 200 It pulls records fine but when I switch it to 2 or another integer above 1 it fails to query any records?
is this a syntax issue? thank you in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROWNUM` is assigned when a row is evaluated for the `where` conditions. The first row from the row source is retrieved and given `ROWNUM=1`. If one of the `were` conditions is `ROWNUM > 1`, this row will not be selected.

Then `ROWNUM=1` is **reassigned** to the next row (which again will fail the `where` clause) and so on. This is because in the end `ROWNUM` must run consecutively from 1, it will not be a sequence with gaps. So any condition that doesn't allow `ROWNUM` to be 1 (example: `where mod(ROWNUM, 2) = 0`) will produce zero rows, and for exactly the same reason.